# Mandar datos de un modelo a otro modelo con django y python

Tags: python, django

necesito mandar datos de mi modelo 1 a modelo 2 porque en modelo uno ya tengo el formulario sin problemas y guarda y se muestra , pero quiero que cuando se guarde el formulario 1 o modelo 1, guardar unos datos de ese modelo 1 al modelo 2 , ya existe el modelo pero no logro mandar los datos del modelo 1 al modelo 2, también ya tengo la parte de guardar y sin problema(cree una función para guardar en la bd del modelo 2).

class Cliente(models.Model):

```
author=models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='blog_post',on_delete=models.CASCADE,default=User)
nombre_cliente=models.CharField(max_length=100,help_text='Ingresa el Nombre del Comprador',)
telefono = models.CharField(max_length=10,help_text='Telefono o Celular',)
municipio = models.CharField(max_length=150,choices=tuple(Punto.get_municipios()),default=1,)
cp = models.CharField(max_length=150,choices=tuple(Punto.get_cp_municipio()),default=1,)
colonia = models.CharField(max_length=200,choices=tuple(Punto.get_colonia_por_cp()),default=1,)
manzana = models.CharField(max_length=5,help_text='Ingresa la manzana',)
numero_lote = models.CharField(max_length=5,help_text='Ingresa numero de lote',)
m2_lote = models.CharField(max_length=5,default=None)
costo_del_terreno = models.CharField(max_length=11,help_text='Costo Terreno',default=0)
deuda_de_terreno = models.CharField(max_length=11,default=0)
a_cuenta_de_terreno = models.CharField(max_length=10)
compromiso_de_pago = models.CharField(max_length=10,help_text='Compromiso Pago',default=0)
cantidad_en_conciliacion = models.CharField(max_length=10,help_text='Cantidad en Conciliacion',default=0)
estatus_pago = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=choises.status_pago, default='nuevo')
notificaciones = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=choises.status_notificacion, default='recibo')
fecha_de_revision = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
fecha_de_entrega = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
abono_pago = models.CharField(max_length=7,default=0)
codigo = models.CharField(max_length=100,default=format)
create = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True) 
update = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

de el modelo 1 o Cliente, al momento de guardar quiero tomar algunos datos y mandarlos a una funcion o al modelo 2 y para que con los datos que lleguen, procedo a guardar en la BD del modelo 2(ya tengo la parte de guardar del modelo 1 y 2, pero de forma individual) y lo que requiero es que sea en automatico porque realmente tengo todos los datos para solo guardar y no es necesario que el usuario abra un formulario y capture de nuevo.

modelo 2
class Pago(models.Model):

```
create = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True) 
update = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
fecha_de_pago = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
comprobante_de_pago=models.FileField(upload_to="clientes/filesbk/",null=True)
nombre_cliente_pago=models.CharField(max_length=100,null=True)
codigo=models.CharField(max_length=30,null=True)
estatus_pago=models.CharField(max_length=10, default='nuevo')
```

asi es como probe en modelo 2 , manualmente

Pago.objects.create(nombre_cliente_pago='  MATILDE GARCIA JAUREGUI',comprobante_de_pago='clientes/FilePDF/ACI114082022201748.pdf',codigo='14082022201355ACI')

una vez que reciba los datos, solo es colocarlos dentro de los datos manuales .

de antemano gracias a todos !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tienes varias opciones para ejecutar operaciones (por ejemplo, crear otro objeto del modelo 2) tras guardar los datos del primer modelo. Ahí van algunas:

## Hacerlo en el `save` del modelo 1

Los modelos tienen una función `save` que se ejecuta cada vez que se guarda un objeto. Cuidado, esto se ejecuta siempre que se graba, bien sea en la creación del objeto o en la modificación.

```
class Modelo1(models.Model):
    ... # tus campos

    def save(self, force_insert=False, force_update=False, using=None, update_fields=None):
        # Crea aquí el objeto del modelo 2
        # Puedes hacerlo con get_or_create para evitar crearlo también en la modificación de datos del modelo 1, si es que es tu caso.
        ...
        return super().save(....)
```

## Hacerlo en el `save` del formulario

Si estás utilizando un `ModelForm`, que sería lo ideal, también puedes ejecutar esta operación en el `save` del `ModelForm` en lugar de hacerlo en el `save` del `Model`.

Sería algo así:

```
class Modelo1Form(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Modelo1
        fields = '__all__' # o como quiera que lo estés haciendo, esto da igual.


    ...

    def save(self, commit=True):
        objeto1 = super().save(commit=commit)
        # Aquí puedes crear tu objeto del modelo 2 utilizando los campos del modelo 1.
        return objeto1
```

## Hacerlo con `signals`

Django te permite "capturar" eventos que ocurren en los modelos con la herramienta [signals](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/signals/). Echa un vistazo a la docu para saber un poco más.
Esto se haría de la siguiente forma:

En la carpeta de tu aplicación debe haber un archivo `__init.py__`. Añade ahí, si no lo está ya, cual es el archivo de configuración de la aplicación. Típicamente es `NombreDeLaAplicacionConfig`. Por ejemplo:

```
# __init__.py
default_app_config = 'tu_aplicacion.apps.TuAplicacionConfig'
```

Luego, si no la hay, crea tu `apps.py` con un contenido similar a este, con el que le, entre otras cosas, le indicarás a la aplicación que tenga en cuenta el archivo donde generarás los manejadores de las señales:

```
# apps.py
from django.apps import AppConfig

class TuAplicacionConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'tu_aplicacion'

    def ready(self):
        from tu_aplicacion import signals
```

Ahora sí, vamos al archivo de las señales, donde diremos qué debe pasar cuando se cree un objeto del modelo 1:

```
# signals.py
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver

@receiver(post_save, sender=Modelo1)
def modelo1_handler(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        # crea aquí tu objeto del modelo 2
```

Yo suelo utilizar más la opción del formulario, pero depende mucho de tu implementación.

Comment: Hola  mil gracias, lo realizare y así mismo investigare la documentación de signals.

Comment: muchísimas gracias , funciono y logre avanzar mucho , mil gracias Daniel!